# unityで、住所を緯度経度に変換したい

Tags: unity2d

unityで、住所を入力すると緯度経度に変換されるプログラムを組みたいのですが、可能でしょうか？

可能であればその方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

unityは使っていないのですが、思いついたので参考までに。ピントはずれならごめんなさい。

> 住所を入力すると緯度経度に変換されるプログラム

ですが、いくつかある選択肢から住所を選んで変換するならともかく、ユーザーに入力させて変換するとなると、えらい大掛かりなDBと自然言語処理などが必要になります。

そこで、[GoogleのGeocoding API](https://www.geocoding.jp/api/)を使ったらどうでしょう。Webアクセスが必要になるので、[ここらあたり](https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html)を参考に。